# When i click on Shopnow Button The Url is Appending to the Site Url and Showing 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my site When Click on The Shop now Button the URL is not Opening on in the Next tab instead it is Appending to the Site URL only and Showing 404 Error How to Come out of this.. 
Here Is My Site URL:http://www.freecouponadda.in/   Devloped in Wordpress

Comment: see if links are starting with "http://" or "https://". If not they will append to domain name.

Comment: provide shop now button code